# How to render HTML hierarchy correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I need to deal with the front-end of my application only. I understand how to write the templates but, for some reason, a few specific elements jump out of the hierarchy I've created:

```rb
%html
  %head
    %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'http-equiv': 'Content-Type' }
    %title Title
  %body{ data: { action: action_name, controller: controller_name.camelcase } }
    .page-container
      = render 'application/timeout'

      %header
        = render 'application/cookie_banner'

        .container
          .row
            .logo.col-3
              = link_to root_path do
                = image_tag 'logo.jpg'
            .login.col-9
              = render 'application/user_information'

      %nav.navbar.navbar-expand.navbar-light
        = render 'navigation/by_role'
      .content-container.container
        .row
          %section
            .section-container
              = render 'application/notifications'
              = render 'application/flash'
              = yield

      = render 'application/footer'
```

I want to wrap the page in `'.page-container'`, but the footer and `content-container.container` elements are outside the wrapper:

[image]

I need the rendering to follow my element hierarchy.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the image, and cut/paste the HTML into the question, formatting it appropriately for readability, without using "edit" or "update" type tags. "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)" and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)" explain. I'd also strongly recommend reading  "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.